# bash script to auto run on boot, make screen, execute a command and detach

Tags: linux, server, centos7

I am using Centos 7 and on boot I would like to:

- Make a screen
- Execute a command: osrm-routed --algorithm=MLD
  ~/osrm-backend/profiles/australia-latest.osrm
- Detatch from screen (possibly not needed, just as long as I can
  access it myself after its running in future)

Here is something I have thought about, although not correct and wont work

filename: mapstart.sh
Contents of file:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -dmS mapapi osrm-routed --algorithm=MLD ~/osrm-backend/profiles/australia-latest.osrm
```

With your help with the script. I am not sure the best way to run that on boot with centos 7.

Appreciate your help and input.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78017/running-screen-through-a-reboot-cron-job

Comment: I had tried the answers however no go on centos 7 (or for me).

Comment: For example. the following in crontab did not work.

@reboot /usr/bin/screen -d -m osrm-routed --algorithm=MLD ~/osrm-backend/profiles/australia-latest.osrm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who would like to know. The issue was with OSRM and centos. I was able to get it running using the full paths of everything and the following in crontab -e

To get the full path of osrm-backend i ran the command of:

```
which osrm-routed
```

It returned the result of:

```
/usr/local/bin/osrm-routed
```

That then enabled me to add the full path of the command I was trying to run from crontab -e which is required. From there it worked running the below in crontab -e

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -dm -S pistartup /usr/local/bin/osrm-routed --algorithm=MLD ~/osrm-backend/profiles/australia-latest.osrm
```

**break down of all the above:**

runs command at reboot only:

```
@reboot
```

full path to screen command:

```
/usr/bin/screen
```

create screen with name of pistartup and detach:

```
-dm -S pistartup
```

my particular command i wanted to run inside the screen:

```
/usr/local/bin/osrm-routed --algorithm=MLD ~/osrm-backend/profiles/australia-latest.osrm
```

Now when ever the machine is rebooted. it has created a screen and run my command. To resume the screen manually If i ever wanted to, i could issue the command of:

```
screen -r pistartup
```